# How to stop execution of a called method in java and continue execution of calling method

Tags: java

Consider the following code snipett:

```
public String testMethod1(int i, int j)
{
//do something
testmethod2(i,j);
return "some string";
}

public String testMethod2(int i, int j)
{
//do something
if(some condition)
{
//Stop execution of this method
//continue execution of previous method as if this method was never called
}
return "some string";
}
```

Is there a way that we can achieve something like above in java. I want the second method to stop its execution and the first method should continue as if the second method was never called

Comment: worst way `public String testmethod2(int i,int j{ try{ int i=1/0;} finally{return something"}}`

Comment: Return null in m2 and check for it in 1. You could also throw an exception, but this is not a good choice for controlflow.

Comment: You could put a `return ""` in `if(some condition) { ... }`.

Comment: Returning control to a method caller is achieved with a `return` statement, the "as if this method was never called" part is cleanup that you have to handle yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In your `testMethod2`, you should `return` to stop its execution. However, just a plain `return` is not enough as your method returns a `String`. You must return a `String` or null.

My suggestion is to return an empty string (`""`). Why not return null? Because the calling method may want to do something with the string returned. If it is null, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown, which is not good!

So you should do this:

```
if (some condition) {
    return "";
}
```